# How to contol link margin & padding in a NavBar?

Tags: html, css

I have written this codepen for a [Top Navbar](https://codepen.io/SSteven/pen/jdgyoj).

This Top Navbar is a <div> element containing <a> elements:

```
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news" class="active">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>

<h1>TopNav using div and a elements</h1>
```

The key CSS is as follows:

```
.topnav {
  background-color: #bbb; /* gray */
  line-height: 50px; /* same as height! */
}

.topnav a {
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

I have vertically centered the links in the <div> element, by:
1) giving each link a height of 50px and then
2) giving the wrapping <div> the same line-height.
This works fine.

The problem is that I am unable to precisely control the padding and margin for the links.

Right now, I have given the padding for the links an arbitrary value:

```
  padding: 15px 20px;
```

However, there is a small gap at the top and bottom of each link, where the Navbar background color shows through. This can be seen when you hover over a link.

When a link is moused over, I would link the link color to cover the entire NavBar. Is there any exact calculation I can make to ensure this, rather than choosing an arbitrary value for padding-top?

Secondly, there is also a gap at the sides of each link when one hovers. It can be clearly seen when one hovers over a link that is on either side of the "active" link (the green one). I would prefer this gap to be eliminated. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Default `a` tag is `inline` element, you should change it **display** property to `display: inline-block`. so that you can set margin and padding.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Extra small devices (phones) */
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: powderblue;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: #bbb; /* gray */
  line-height: 50px; /* same as height! */
}

.topnav a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block; /* Set inline-block for a tag */
}
  
.topnav {
  background-color: #bbb; /* gray */
  line-height: 50px; /* same as height! */
}


.topnav a.active {
  background-color: mediumseagreen;
  color: white;
}

.topnav a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #f1f1f1; /* light gray */
}
```

```html
    <div class="topnav">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#news" class="active">News</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
    </div>

    <h1>TopNav using div and a elements</h1>
```

Comment: What about the gap on the sides of the links?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ this post will help you to remove gaps between the sides of the links

Comment: I have tried the basic scheme suggested by you and it works fine. To eliminate the space, I tried `float: left;` on the `a` element. This eliminates the gap alright, but now the background color on the navbar disappears. Click on the original [codepen](https://codepen.io/SSteven/pen/jdgyoj). Any suggestions?

Comment: use clearfix in your .topnav class `.topnav::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
`

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I was looking for - a solution for a minimal browser that supports only float/clear. Now I can progressively enhance this for browsers with flexbox support and then with grid support. Thanks.

Comment: it looks perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Use this. I gave `display:block` to `a` and `display:flex` to `.topnav`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Extra small devices (phones) */
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: powderblue;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: #bbb; /* gray */
  height:50px;
  display:flex;
  line-height: 50px; /* same as height! */
}

.topnav a {
  display:block;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: mediumseagreen;
  color: white;
}

.topnav a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #f1f1f1; /* light gray */
}
```

```html
    <div class="topnav">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#news" class="active">News</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
    </div>

    <h1>TopNav using div and a elements</h1>
```

Comment: For this code snippet, I want to use only float/clear, since this will be used on browsers that don't support flexbox. I intend to progressively enhance this solution to flexbox on a browser that supports flexbox, and then on to grid.